# My OWIN application is not triggering my custom model binder

Tags: model, owin, katana, imodelbinder

I have some dates that come in a weird format (dd.MM.YYYY).  This is something how the business wants it displayed.  So, I need a custom model binder to read this date.  I had this solution working fine, but when I switched over to using OWIN, then it stopped working.  Here is my code right now:

My OWIN startup file:

```
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
      var config = new HttpConfiguration();
      config.BindParameter(typeof(DateTime?), new DateTimeWebApiBinder());
      config.BindParameter(typeof(DateTime), new DateTimeWebApiBinder());  
      app.UseWebApi(config);
    }
```

Custom Model Binder

```
    public class DateTimeWebApiBinder : IModelBinder
    {
      public bool BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
      {
        var incomingDate = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        if (bindingContext.ModelType == typeof(DateTime) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(incomingDate.AttemptedValue)) 
        { 
          return false; 
        }
        DateTime parsedDate;
        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(incomingDate.AttemptedValue, "dd.MM.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out parsedDate))
        {
          bindingContext.Model = parsedDate;
          return true;
        }
        return false;
      }
    }
```

What is happening, is the custom model binder is not triggering.  I suspect it has something to do with the OWIN setup.

Comment: Please consider starting your question with a description of what you are trying to achieve and what is not going as expected.  Reader want some context on what they are reading before being thrown into code examination.

Answer (score 1):

you can try:

```
ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterWebApiModelBinderProvider();
builder.RegisterType<DateTimeWebApiBinder>().AsModelBinderForTypes(typeof(DateTime));


var resolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(builder.Build());

var config = new HttpConfiguration
{
   DependencyResolver = resolver
};
app.UseWebApi(config);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/605595/ASP-NET-MVC-Custom-Model-Binder), you should put `[ModelBinder(typeof(DateTimeWebApiBinder))]` on the parameter of your controller.